# Se detectó una referencia circular al serializar un objeto MVC C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
public JsonResult List() {
   object jsonResult = new {
        productList = productDao.findAllProducts(),
        categoryList = categoryDao.findAllCategories()
    };

    return Json(jsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

en C# MVC y cuando intento serializar la lista de product sale el siguiente error:

> Se detectó una referencia circular al serializar un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.product_44663398E72098C15707A5F4D8F5C4AEF9F482061AC8B50053C2FADC993417D4'.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

La referencia circular es cuando tu objeto tiene propiedades de las cuales una de ellas hace referencia a otro objeto con una propiedad igual a la anterior; por ejemplo:

```
public class Padre{

   public string Nombre {get; set;}
   public string Edad {get; set;}
   public string Hijo {get; set;}
}


public class Hijo{
   public string Nombre {get; set;}
   public string Edad {get; set;}
   public string Padre {get; set;}
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior un Padre tiene a un hijo y su hijo a su vez tiene un padre, pero como padre tiene una propiedad hijo comienza a hacer referencia circular, llamandose una y otra vez provocando un loop infinito.

Verifica que tus objetos no tengan propiedades de este tipo.

Comment: Si tienen propiedades de este tipo

Comment: ¿Utilizas entity framework o algo por el estilo para extraer los elementos?

Comment: esto se genera a la relacion que tiene product y category, el cual necesito navegar en una categoria asociada al producto ejemplo: product.category.category_name

Comment: utilizo entity framemework ADO.Net

Comment: ya lo realice pero me devuelve el objeto categoria dentro de product para realizar la siguiente navegación: product.category.category_name

Comment: Puedes probar eliminando el atributo 'virtual' de una de tus propiedades de la entidad que dan la referencia circular, esto evitará traer todos los objetos de la relacion. Ej. public virtual ICollection<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }  a public ICollection<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }

Comment: no funciono eliminando el atributo virtual

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer es serializar tu JSON utilizando la libreria Json.NET de Newtonsoft tomandola de NuGet, esta tiene soporte para este tipo de referencias y puede hacerlo de una forma similar en tu metodo .                                                                                            public JsonResult List() {
   object jsonResult = new {
        productList = productDao.findAllProducts(),
        categoryList = categoryDao.findAllCategories()
    };

    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult), "application/json");
}

Answer (score 0):

La explicacion de Angel Ruiz es correcta, la recomendacion aqui es (si no quieres pelear con Entity Framework) crear DTOs (Data Transfer Objects), estos tienen la misma definicion que tus entidades, pero tienen la ventaja de ser objetos POCO (Plain OLD CLR Objects) que no tienen relacion con EntityFramework, al crear los POCOS deja fuera las propiedades con referencias circulares y podras serializar correctamente.

```
public class PadreDTO
{
  public string Nombre {get; set;}
  public string Edad {get; set;}
  public string Hijo {get; set;}
}


public class HijoDTO
{
  public string Nombre {get; set;}
  public string Edad {get; set;}
  //public string Padre {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: no funciono removiento virtual, y en el caso de los dto necesito es navegar de la siguiente forma: product.category.category_name

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo explica bien Angel Ruiz.
Puedes especificar que propiedades se deben ignorar para la generación del json.
Para el ejemplo anterior donde hay un padre con un hijo aquí te dejo el ejemplo.

```
public class Padre{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Nombre {get; set;}
    public string Edad {get; set;}

    public int IdHijo {get; set;}

    [ScriptIgnore]
    [ForeignKey("IdHijo")]
    public Hijo Hijo {get; set;}
}


public class Hijo{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Nombre {get; set;}
    public string Edad {get; set;}

    public int IdPadre {get; set;}

    [ScriptIgnore]
    [ForeignKey("IdPadre")]
    public string Padre {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes algún objeto que al serializar pueda tener una referencia circular y  necesitas además que al deserializarlo también esté, añade esto en la definición de tus objetos.

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

Si no necesitas la referencia circular, deberás hacer un ignore de estas referencias circulares o tener un nivel de profundidad de objetos que no pueda crear estas.

Answer (score -1):

Tenia ese error y los resolvi con esto:

```
var list = from I in obj.Impuestoes
                       select new
                       {
                           I.Id_Impuesto,
                           I.Nombre,
                           I.Porciento,
                           I.Tipo
                       };
```